# Firebase Cloud Function no console.log when admin.firestore() is called

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a webhook to recieve facebook messenger events in a cloud function like so:

```
export const facebookMessengerHook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.method);
    console.log(req.body);
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        const body = req.body;

        console.log(body);
        // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
        if (body.object === 'page') {
            res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');

            // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
            for (const entry of body.entry) {
                // will only ever contain one message, so we get index 0
                const webhook_data = entry.messaging[0];

                console.log(webhook_data);
                try {
                    // v THAT PART HERE v
                    const user = await admin.firestore().collection('users')
                        .where('facebookMessengerId', '==', webhook_data.sender.id)
                        .get();
                    // ^ THAT PART HERE ^
                    console.log(user);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('No user');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    }
});
```

It does not log anything, unless I comment out the marked part in the snippet.

Can someone please explain to me why and how to fix this, because I need to make a call to firestore and I also need the console.log for debug purposes?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That is quite odd. I understand you are getting the logs for everything else normally. So not logging just the `user` you got within your `try` statement?

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez No this does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most probably comes from the fact that by doing

```
res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
```

you actually indicate to the Cloud Function platform that the Cloud Function can be terminated before the rest of the asynchronous work (the set of calls to the `get()` method) is done. See the following official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3) form more detail. In other words, the Cloud Function is terminated before the promises returned by the `get()` method are resolved.

So you should modify your code as follows:

```
    //....
    if (body.object === 'page') {


        // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
        for (const entry of body.entry) {
            // will only ever contain one message, so we get index 0
            const webhook_data = entry.messaging[0];

            console.log(webhook_data);
            try {

                const user = await admin.firestore().collection('users')
                    .where('facebookMessengerId', '==', webhook_data.sender.id)
                    .get();

                console.log(user);


            } catch (e) {
                console.log('No user');
                //Here throw an error to be catched at an upper level
            }
        }

        res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
    }
    //....
```

---

Note that you may use `Promise.all()` since you issue a series of fetch to the database. But with your code it is impossible to confirm that, because it does not show the exact use of these fetches.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you. Do you have any explanation, why it runs normally without the await call? I remember that async functions actually run synchronously until the first await call (or something similar to that), so it definitly has something to do with that. I just thought I can send the answer to facebook and handle the rest after that, because facebook is really pushy about the speed of the answer (I think only 2 seconds or something like that).

Comment: What do you mean by "Do you have any explanation, why it runs normally without the await call"?

Comment: So if I comment out the await call, everything gets logged and the function terminates correctly, even when the `res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');` is before everything. Just when I add anything that is awaited, I get no console.logs. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: If you remove the await there is nothing asynchronous anymore in the Cloud Function and (in most of the cases, if not all) it has the time to execute the console logs before being killed.

Comment: I don't really understand the reasoning for that.

Comment: Using await doesn't change the fact that the `get()` method is asynchronous. It just "pauses" the execution and resumes when the promise returned by the method resolves. As said, by doing `res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');` you indicate to the Cloud Function platform that the Cloud Function can be terminated. This may happen "immediately" or after some time, it all depends on the Cloud Function platform and is completely out of our control (serveless platfom).

Comment: So in most of the cases, the CF is killed before the promises returned by the `get()` methods resolve, but it could happens that the CF is not immediately killed and that it works. On the other hand, most of the time it has the time to execute the console logs before being killed, but it could happens that it is killed before and you would not see any console.log. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I do understand what you say, but what confuses me is, why the console.logs **before** the `res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');` are not beeing shown in the log, when `await` is present.

Comment: I don't know. They should.

Comment: Yeah ok. Might be just some firebase quirk. I thought maybe someone knows about this. Thank you for your help though! :)